# Read Multilple json schema with spark

Tags: json, scala, amazon-web-services, hadoop2, amazon-emr

Software Configuration:

```
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.3
Applications:Hive 2.3.2, Pig 0.17.0, Hue 4.1.0, Spark 2.3.0
```

Tried to read with multiple json schema,

> val df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema",
>   "true").json("s3a://s3bucket/2018/01/01/*")

Throws an error,

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for JSON. It must be specified manually.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$9.apply(DataSource.scala:207)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$9.apply(DataSource.scala:207)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:206)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:397)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:340)
```

How to read json with multipl schema's with spark?

Comment: In general there shouldn't be any problem to read json's with multiple schema's (you even don't need mergeSchema option, it's related to Parquet). Can you share more details about your scenario, because I can't reproduce this error even when reading json's with very conflicting schema's.

Comment: Also, did you try to run it locally, do you get the same error ?

Comment: Yes I did. I get the same error if I run against different schemas. It works fine for parquet files.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens when you are pointing to wrong path (when data does not exist).